# Remote Debug Aplication On Windows Server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, windows-server-2008, remote-debugging

I have a Windows 2008 r2 server. I just deployed my ASP.Net application to it. I am getting some errors.

I know that I can debug the application using the remote debugger, but what if visual studio is not installed on the remote machine?

Is the there a way to debug the application without actually having to install Visual Studio on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Visual Studio includes a little tool, [Remote Debugging Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx), msvsmon.exe, which is all you need on the server for remote debugging to work.

The debugging monitor can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=475), or you can just copy the files from your Visual Studio installation to the server. You should be able to find the files here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger
```

You can setup the TCP port used for communication in MSVSMON and Visual Studio, the default is port 135. Obviously, any firewalls between the machines must allow TCP communications on the selected port.